# Alternative to Publishing on WAS in RAD

Tags: eclipse, performance, websphere, publish, rad

I am working on WAS on RAD 7.5 and publishing and making changes as very slow and frustrating..

Is there any other faster alternative like using eclipse and any other server to develop and eventually run it on WAS-RAD system ?

I heard somewhere we can use the dump of mysql and use it something like it but have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try was development profile or liberty profile.

if you don't have enough money :) you can use tomcat and embedded ejb container as alternative.. it would be faster ..but you will need to take care while packaging to tomacat and to  websphere

Comment: WebSphere Developer Edition is free, including Liberty Profile for 8.5. But it is a key point that you have to be careful with server-specific behaviors when you test on one server then deploy to a different one. We've definitely done this at times, but we've also definitely had server-specific issues that we didn't discover until later in the process than is ideal.